# Can't access (only) some of an object's properties (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase / AngularJS, but I think this is a plain JavaScript object structure problem in my opinion.

Signing in Facebook manually with firebase, I cannot get access to 4 specific properties that are inside the "result" object from the signInWithCredential process.

(console) Logging the "result" object, the 4 variables are in there indeed, I just cannot get direct access to them.

However, I can get access to all the other properties of the object, which turns this into a really weird bug.

Here is the code :

```
firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential).then(function(result){

     // $localStorage.firebaseToken = result.providerData.stsTokenManager.accessToken;


        var chatUserData = {};
        var updates = {};


        console.log("result str obj : " + JSON.stringify(result)); // defined

    console.log("result str > uid is " + JSON.stringify(result.uid)); // defined
        console.log("result str > displayName is " + JSON.stringify(result.displayName)); // defined
        console.log("result str > photoURL is " + JSON.stringify(result.photoURL)); // defined
        console.log("result str > email is " + JSON.stringify(result.email)); // defined
        console.log("result str > emailVerified is " + JSON.stringify(result.emailVerified)); // defined
        console.log("result str > isAnonymous is " + JSON.stringify(result.isAnonymous)); // defined

        console.log("result str Provider Data " + JSON.stringify(result.providerData)); // array of objects - defined

        console.log("result str > apiKey is " + JSON.stringify(result.apiKey)); // gets undefined
        console.log("result str > appName is " + JSON.stringify(result.appName)); // gets undefined
        console.log("result str > authDomain is " + JSON.stringify(result.authDomain)); // gets undefined
        console.log("result str > stsTokenManager is " + JSON.stringify(result.stsTokenManager)); // gets undefined     


        chatUserData.username = result.displayName;
        chatUserData.email = $localStorage.fb_data.data.email;
        chatUserData.id = result.uid;

        updates['/users/' + result.uid + "/"] = chatUserData;
        firebase.database().ref().update(updates);

     }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error! " + JSON.stringify(error));
     });
```

And here is the object code from the console log :

[image: result_object]

which makes this into a weird bug because I know the object is there, and supposedly I'm accessing it right, but it just doesn't load. This is usually just a stupid mistake I made, but I just can't seem to find it.

(the facebook profile I have there is fake)

Hope you guys can help, Cheers.

Comment: Why do you need JSON.stringify? it makes sense with objects, but with values simply do console.log(result.displayName)

Comment: Because some of those values are objects and logging them would turn out in [Object object].
Either way, I tried it without the JSON.stringify and the results are the same. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this, turns out this is a kind of firebase-managed object, the way to correctly loop through it is using angular.foreach. And even that way is not the correct one.

I should have used user.getToken(), and I found it right in the documentation.

[Firebase User Get Token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#getToken)